# How to make a context menu to react event's Fullcalendar?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, jsx, contextmenu, fullcalendar-4

I have a full calendar and I want to make a context menu when I right click on the event.

I used this https://codesandbox.io/s/fullcalendar-react-7nggi?fontsize=14&file=/src/DemoApp.jsx

But I want just when I right click on the event not on the calendar.

How can I it ?

Comment: that's strange, what you've done looks like it should work

Comment: I want that it works only when I right clicked on the event not on the all calendar

Comment: I know. But I'm saying that what you've done should achieve that, it's unclear why it doesn't

Comment: I try to do that, but it's the same issue

Comment: do what? I didn't suggest anything new.